# can I omit parameter name in lambda in Java

Tags: java, swift, lambda, java-8

can I **omit parameter name** in **lambda** in Java, and I can use `$0, $1...` to replace them like Swift's [Closure Expressions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID95).

`BiConsumer<String, Integer> bc = (s, i) -> System.out.println(s + "  " + i);`

omit parameter name like this:
`BiConsumer<String, Integer> bc1 = System.out.println($0 + "  " + $1);`

`$0` is first parameter, `$1` is second parameter

Comment: To quote [Java-8:Lambdas](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-lambdas-part1-2080972.html) - *A lambda in Java essentially consists of three parts: a parenthesized set of parameters, an arrow, and then a body, which can either be a single expression or a block of Java code.*

Answer (score 4):

No.

There is no way to omit parameter names, and or use a shorthand version like `$n` (except if you count using a method reference, which is not the same thing).

Answer (score 4):

No, but I believe you can

```
public void printBiConsumer(String s,  Integer i){
    System.out.println(s + " " + i);
}
BiConsumer<String, Integer> bc = this::printBiConsumer;
```

But as Bohemian said, this is not the same thing as swift closures.

Comment: `this::printBiConsumer`

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
BiConsumer<String, Integer> bc1 = System.out.println($0 + "  " + $1);
```

was already a syntactically correct statement prior to Java 8. It’s meaning is “concatenate the value of `$0`, the constant `" "`, and the value of `$1` to a string and pass it to an invocation of `System.out.println` and assign the result to the newly declared variable `bc1`”.

This will ultimately get rejected by the compiler because the `println` method’s return type is incompatible with `BiConsumer<String, Integer>`, but the syntax is indistinguishable from correct invocations with a compatible return type.

So since this syntax does already have a predefined meaning and it’s not even an uncommon construct, it can’t change its meaning just because you’re using the uncommon (but still valid) variable names `$0` and `$1`.

It it was, what should the line

```
BiConsumer<String, Integer> bc = foo(bar($0 + "  " + $1));
```

mean?

A) `BiConsumer<String, Integer> bc = foo(($0, $1) -> bar($0 + "  " + $1));`

B) `BiConsumer<String, Integer> bc = ($0, $1) -> foo(bar($0 + "  " + $1));`

C) `BiConsumer<String, Integer> bc = foo(bar(($0, $1) -> $0 + "  " + $1));`